# Is there any if function to skip NA values in excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]

Hi All, I am trying to use average function where it can skip the NA values. As per attached snapshot how can i get the result of correct one which is 200/3. I want to take the count of NA but not while calculating average. I can's use 0 because the value will be calculated as well like the sAMPLE2 snapshot. Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean that in your scenario you want it to be 200/3 (The sum divided by the count of cells)? If so you can do `=SUM(D2:D4)/COUNTA(D2:D4)` This will sum the range then divide by the count of all the cells that are not empty. If this is not it, then please clarify a bit better what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Simon Sum function would return #N/A when we have any #N/A in the range. use sumif instead to ignore #N/A

Comment: Anmol, not sure if you noticed, they're not actual NA errors. Just looks to be NA written in.

Comment: Ideally i am trying to look for 3 months average from a data set. Ex - In Jan they have NA based on my formula, feb they have 100 & march 100, so the average should say 200/3 (though they didnt have anything in jan but still i want to show it as a count while taking the average.

Comment: Yes @Simon, in case this is not #N/A Errors then your formula is correct.

Comment: @BimalSubhasis So you want it to actually say "200/3" rather than calculate it? If so you could try `=SUM(D2:D4)&"/"&COUNTA(D2:D4)`

Comment: @Simon - i want to show the result as 66.67, the calculation should be as 200/3

Comment: @BimalSubhasis right well then my initial comment will do that. All good.

Answer (score 1):

`AGGREGATE` is able to do this:
`=AGGREGATE(1,4,your_range)`
1 is to activate the AVERAGE function;
4 is to ignore error values.

Answer (score 0):

There are different functions which can do that: there is `=IfNA()` and there is `=IfError()` worksheet functions.

You can use worksheet functions in VBA, using `Application.WorkSheetFunction` object, like `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfNA()` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError()`.

More information can be found in the [IFNA documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifna-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461) or the [IFERROR documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of SumIf <> # NA and CountA function as both have ability to ignore errors.

```
SUMIF(D2:D4,"<>#N/A")/COUNTA(D2:D4)
```

This would help

Comment: Thanks Anmol, let me try